# Schema parsing error with flink-connector-cassandra "UnresolvedUserTypeException: Cannot resolve user type system_distributed.duration"

Tags: cassandra, apache-flink, scylla, flink-connector-cassandra

Context : We have a flink application that consumes data from kafka and sinks the data onto Scylla DB

When the application starts there is a **Schema parsing error**

Why are we getting this error ?

Flink Version : **1.15.4**

Scylla DB version : **scylla-enterprise-2022.2.11-0**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-connector-cassandra_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>1.15.4</version>
</dependency>
```

```
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2023-08-11 09:16:04.567 [Source: Custom Source -> Map -> Sink: Cassandra Sink (7/9)#0] ERROR com.datastax.driver.core.SchemaParser  - Error parsing schema for table system_distributed.service_levels: Cluster.getMetadata().getKeyspace("system_distributed").getTable("service_levels") will be missing or incomplete
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnresolvedUserTypeException: Cannot resolve user type system_distributed.duration
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DataTypeCqlNameParser.parse(DataTypeCqlNameParser.java:147)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.TableMetadata.build(TableMetadata.java:188)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SchemaParser.buildTables(SchemaParser.java:176)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SchemaParser.buildKeyspaces(SchemaParser.java:128)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SchemaParser.refresh(SchemaParser.java:64)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.refreshSchema(ControlConnection.java:341)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.tryConnect(ControlConnection.java:271)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:199)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:77)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1414)
```

Any input will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Cannot resolve user type system_distributed.duration` message indicates that the underlying driver is unaware of the `duration` type.

Upgrade the driver at least to [v3.2.0](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.3/changelog/#3-2-0), which is the initial version supporting durations. Notice that the latest Java driver is already at v4.17, so prefer switching to v4.x if Flink already supports the newer driver API.

Comment: thanks will try upgrading the flink to higher version which is using higher driver version

Answer (score 1):

It was interesting to see from the stack trace you posted that the Java driver used by the Cassandra connector didn't know how to deal with the `duration` type:

```
...
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnresolvedUserTypeException: Cannot resolve user type system_distributed.duration
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DataTypeCqlNameParser.parse(DataTypeCqlNameParser.java:147)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.TableMetadata.build(TableMetadata.java:188)
        ...
```

so I had to check which version the connector was using.

I was very surprised to find that [the Cassandra connector in Flink 1.15.4 is using Cassandra Java driver v3.0.0](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.15.4/flink-connectors/flink-connector-cassandra/pom.xml#L41):

```
        <driver.version>3.0.0</driver.version>
```

That version of the Java driver was [released all the way back to January 2016](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/releases/tag/3.0.0). Support for the `duration` type was added to the Java driver a year later ([JAVA-1347](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1347)).

The Cassandra connector in [Flink 1.16.0 uses Java driver 3.11.2](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.16.0/flink-connectors/flink-connector-cassandra/pom.xml#L40) ([released in April 2022](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/releases/tag/3.11.2)) which has `duration` type support.

Note that the Cassandra connector was moved out of the Flink tree and into a dedicated repository [flink-connector-cassandra](https://github.com/apache/flink-connector-cassandra) ([FLINK-29982](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-29982)). Cheers!

Comment: Ya after upgrading to flink 1.16 , this issue is resolved now